# Autofac Hangfire No parameterless constructor error

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, autofac, hangfire

Im encountering issue on Hangfire on my setup. I always saw this error on
Hangfire.State table

Retry attempt 1 of 10: No parameterless constructor defined for this obj…
Though after several retries. It somehow resolved automatically.

I'm not good with Autofac, just mostly basic. Also my first time using Hangfire.

Here are my setup. Using Autofac.

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("connectionstring");

    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    builder.RegisterType<CSVCompanyAImporter>().Named<ISpecificImporter>("CSVCompanyAImporter").PropertiesAutowired();
    builder.RegisterType<CSVImporter>().Named<IImporter>("CSVImporter").PropertiesAutowired();
    builder.RegisterType<ImportManager>().AsSelf().PropertiesAutowired();

    var container = builder.Build();

    JobActivator.Current = new AutofacJobActivator(container);
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseAutofacActivator(container);

    app.UseHangfireDashboard();
    app.UseHangfireServer();
}

public class ImportManager
{
    public IImporter Importer { get; set; }
    public IIndex<string, IImporter> Importers { get; set; }
    private bool IsAutofacNamed { get; set; }

    public ImportManager(IImporter importer)
    {
        this.Importer = importer;
        this.IsAutofacNamed = false;
    }

    public ImportManager(IIndex<string, IImporter> importers)
    {
        this.Importers = importers;
        this.IsAutofacNamed = true;
    }

    public void Execute(string importType, string specificImportType)
    {
        if (IsAutofacNamed)
        {
            this.Importer = this.Importers[importType];
            this.Importer.InitializeSpecificImport(specificImportType);
        }

        bool hasFiles = this.Importer.LocateFile();

        if(hasFiles)
        { 
            this.Importer.ReadFile();
            this.Importer.ImportFile();
        }
    }
}

public class CSVImporter : IImporter
{
    public CSVImporter(ISpecificImporter specificImporter)
    {}
    
    public CSVImporter(IIndex<string, ISpecificImporter> specificImporters)
    {}
}

public class CSVCompanyAImporter : ISpecificImporter
{
    public CSVCompanyAImporter() {}
}
```

And where the Hangfire is being called.

```
    string importId = "CompanyAImport"

    RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<ImportManager>(importId, importManager => importManager.Execute("CSVImporter", "CSVCompanyAImporter"), Cron.Minutely);
```

Here is the exception details:

> {"FailedAt":"2017-11-10T06:20:00.1294044Z","ExceptionType":"System.MissingMethodException","ExceptionMessage":"No parameterless constructor defined for this object.","ExceptionDetails":"System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.\r\n   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)\r\n   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)\r\n   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)\r\n   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)\r\n   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)\r\n   at Hangfire.JobActivator.ActivateJob(Type jobType)\r\n   at Hangfire.JobActivator.SimpleJobActivatorScope.Resolve(Type type)\r\n   at Hangfire.Server.CoreBackgroundJobPerformer.Perform(PerformContext context)\r\n   at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.b__0()\r\n   at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.InvokePerformFilter(IServerFilter filter, PerformingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)\r\n   at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.<>c__DisplayClass8_1.<PerformJobWithFilters>b__2()\r\n   at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.PerformJobWithFilters(PerformContext context, IEnumerable`1 filters)\r\n   at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.Perform(PerformContext context)\r\n   at Hangfire.Server.Worker.PerformJob(BackgroundProcessContext context, IStorageConnection connection, String jobId)"}

Any help please. Im stuck with this issue.

Comment: please paste the full text of the exception you get

Comment: Edited post with exception details

Comment: This is odd. The only thing I can see is that IIndex is not registered with the container.

Comment: @pmcilreavy Have you replicated it the same way? Actually after the error, the hangfire will keep on retrying, and somehow (not time-accurately), the hangfire/autofac will resolve and will chose the constructor with Iindex parameter